# Hiding Time Field if Date is Expired

Tags: entities, datetime

My time field shows after an expired date. My client wants to have the time hidden after the expired date. But still have the date show. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes- this is totally possible.

Comment: might i ask how?

Comment: What's your configuration, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7 date field. Using views, when the date has expired, the page goes to a section labeled 'past events.' In the template page, the date and time are both separated for instance.  $date_output and $time_output. I know I could probably create a page that just shows the date output field. but i'm trying to figure out a way to just code it on the current page.